# How to use a real credit card for testing web applications

Tags: javascript, magento

I have written several .js codes to go through a staging website and buy an item.  All is working well.  However, now it is time to move these automated tests to my real website.

The problem is this: My staging account will allow testing credit card numbers to go through (e.g. 4111 1111 1111 1111 visa) however the real website will not (for obvious reasons).  What I want to do is buy and item and then have magento or something automatically see the credit card # know it is mine and cancel the order.  Without me having to email the shipping people every time I run this test.

So the question is:

What are methods people use to do this type of thing online it seams the only questions are about test credit cards and not real ones.

Reasoning:

I want to know when payments are not going through in production, even if the issue exists in some external service that is not managed by us. I don't want to have to wait for a user to report it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I believe most payment services offer sandboxes for payment testing

Comment: You don't. You expect the staging account area to function exactly like production and once all tests pass in staging, release to prod.

Comment: Yes that true @RyanC but I'm also trying to monitor for potential bugs introduced into the real website.

Comment: @Vladimir_314159 If your credit card works correctly in your sandbox/staging area, then any issues that you will see should be with the company's credit card processor, not your code. And in that case, it would impact more than just your application, but anyone else who uses that service.

Comment: ok this makes since but what if I want to check if production is getting orders from the site I,  thus I need something that will go through to them  and the staging site wont test this.

Comment: also expecting the production to work exactly the same as the staging site is maybe a correct theoretical assumption but will not work in practice @RyanC